# Im trying to store querysnapshot document into a local list but for some reason the its not working here is the way i did it

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to
the doc[uid] results into the _following list to use somewhere else but its not working

'''

```
List _followingList = [];

FirebaseFirestore.instance

    .collection('venues')
    .where('followers', arrayContains: user.uid)
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
  
    setState(() {
      _followingList.add(doc['uid']);
    });
  });
});
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use `setState` here.
So, use this line without wrapping it  in a `setState()`

```
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      _followingList.add(doc['uid']);
  });
```